# Argument 'formErrorLogController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use `modalInstance`.
I have the following:

```
$scope.openClaimLogError = function (deni_arr) {
    $scope.data = {
      deni_arr : deni_arr
    };

    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/templates/formErrorLog.html',
        controller: 'formErrorLogController',
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return $scope.data.deni_arr;
            }
        }
    });
}`

This code is in Controller1.js

And in Controller2.js I have the following: 

`'use strict';
    app.controller('formErrorLogController',
    function ($scope, $cookies, claimsService, $modal, $filter, data) {}`
```

What exactly I'm trying to do is to send data to the second controller so I can print it.

Why do I get an error like this: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'formErrorLogController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: you might have not included the script reference

Comment: @Aravind and where shall I do that?

A little more explained: I have a form_page.html, and a formErrorLog.html.html (as above), in form_page.html's controller (controller1.js) i have an array with uncompleted fields, which I want to pass to formErrorLog.html's controller (controller2.js) which will appear on the modal.

Comment: @FineasSilaghi in index.html?

Comment: @tanmay oh, yes. This was the problem. I simply forgot to add it. Thank you!
You can add this as an answer so I can close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error says it has controller missing, you might have missed to include one of the controller files in `index.html` as in using `<script src="..."></script>`. Check for that.